# How to engineer binary vectors (representing store layout) into new variables (for predicting store sales)?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

Suppose we want to predict store sales with store layout. The raw data contain a binary vector for each store representing the configuration. For example, when it has a table, a counter, and a shelf, etc., its layout vector is $(1,1,1,...)$. When it only has a counter, the vector will be $(0,1,0,...)$. Adding or deleting different element will impact store sales differently since it alters different aspects of the layout. For example, adding a counter to a store with table $(1,0,...)$ should be different from adding it to one without a table $(0,0,...)$.

The question is:
How should we engineer the binary vectors for each store into predictors? My starting thoughts are: 1. use PCA to convert the binary vector into the PCA feature scores; 2. construct a distance matrix and run clustering, from which we can calculate the distance between each store's layout and the nearest cluster centroid.

Are there other ways and what would be the "best practices" for dealing with this type of problem?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use PCA and not use the raw data directly to predict store sales? Or why would we cluster the data? We do not care about clusters, we care about the effects of a particular layout (from what I understand at least).

Comment: Thanks for the question. Conceptually, changing a given element will alter the holistic store layout. Adding/deleting the same element will impact store sales differently depending on the original layout.

Comment: Have you tried simply running a regression (with some interactions potentially) using the store sales as a response? This should be your first step. It will also give you the ability to immediately control for more important variables (like store location, reviews, distance to competitors, etc.)

Comment: Hi usεr11852, Yes, I've tried that. But that's a good point. I am just thinking the interactions will be very complicated given that we have a long vector with 50+ elements each.

Comment: Group lasso is your friend then. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Does it account for not just those 2-way interactions? such as 3-way, 4-way, ... up to 50+ way interactions? You know, for store layout, all elements need to be taken into account...

Comment: Not really. It will help if there is a intrinsic grouping among the variables examined. How many instances you have? (Actually it would be good if these figures are added in the body of the original question.)

Comment: If you're interested in allowing for potentially complex interactions, why not a tree-based method (i.e. boosting)? Tree-based models are allowed to be very flexible. In these types of models, adding a counter to a store with a table is allowed to be different from adding it to one without a table.

Comment: Hi, usεr11852 I guess it gives us 2^50 possible layout. Hi, Roland do you mean regression tree?

Comment: @Ray Yang, that would be an ensemble of regression trees.

Comment: @usεr11852, it sounds like what I'm looking for. Could you provide a little bit more pointers or hint on how to implement the ensemble of regression trees? thanks!

Comment: Look at gradient boosting libraries. `mboost` and `xgboost` are two widely used R packages.